# Problems with amsmath

Tags: amsmath

This is my premble to a document and I always get the error LaTeX Error: C
ommand \iint already defined.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%
%\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}`
```

What can I do? Where is the conflict?

Comment: Read [section 2.2](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/wasysym/wasysym.pdf#page=1) from `wasysym` documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `wasysym` should be loaded after `amsmath` *and* be passed the option `nointegrals` (unless you really want the multiple integral symbols in `wasysym` to take over).

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%
%\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last.

From the manual of `wasysym`:

[image]

Actually, the loading order *is* relevant, as you discovered.

Answer (score 5):

If you add (and uncomment)  `\show` commands as I have below, it is easy to see the point at which the commands become defined, in this case `wasysym`. You can `\let` them to `\relax` to undefine them then `amsmath` will give its definitions

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%
%\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\show\iint
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\show\iint
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\usepackage{multirow}
%\show\iint
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\show\iint
```

Comment: Thank you, I am an absolute newbie and I will try to understand this suggestion...