# Commands already defined

Tags: definition

I am getting the following problem

```
(/home/hagbard/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)
! LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

l.659 ...ewcommand{\iint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{2}}
```

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\RequirePackage{wasysym}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter's content...

\end{document}
```

`amsmath` conflicts with `wasysym` due to the redefinition of integrals in `wasysym`.  Although using `amsmath`, I do not want to miss on the astronomical symbols provided by `wasysym`.

Comment: Welcome! Please expand your snippet to a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140456)

Comment: It stops at `amsopn.sty`.  Perhaps that is the problem ?

Comment: you are loading stix, marvosm which do you want?

Comment: Have no idea what is compatible with what actually.

Comment: if you ask for all math to be set in font a then all math to be set in font b, then naturally that can not work but no one but you can decide which font you want. Just pick one not two.

Comment: but now you have removed marvosym there is no error from your example in texlive 2023 or 2022, or 2021

Comment: I am trying to replicate the `\iint already defined` but I am not quite there yet.  Do you think it is font related ?

Comment: amsmath has specific code to avoid conflicting with stix, you should not get the errr from the code posted

Comment: With `marvosym` I get `\Hermaphrodite` error which is something different.

Comment: No I do not get the error from the code posted as MWE requested.

Comment: well that's not helpful:-) I suggest you delete until you have an example then undelete

Comment: Ok.  This might be of value though `l.659 ...ewcommand{\iint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{2}}`

Comment: as i say if you load multiple packages all redefining the same commands such errors are expected. but can not guess which packages you are using if you show only unrelated code and a fragment of error message

Comment: They are bad packages then as they should not be made to conflict.

Comment: that's just line 659 of amsmath, what you have not shown is how you defined `\iint` before loading `amsmath`

Comment: of _couse_ they conflict,  it is user error not a bad package. If one package says make math red and another  package says make math green, neither package is wrong but it is user error to use both at the same time

Comment: I have not redefined the command myself, must be from the `RequirePackage` part.

Comment: Looks like others have had the problem too, 4 years ago. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510948/error-command-iint-already-defined]

Comment: I have figured out that the problem originated from `\RequirePackage{wasysym}`.

Comment: It is quite a problem because I will miss the astronomical symbols.

Comment: I shall complain to Axel, to have a solution.

Comment: @Mahavir The "problem" is probably easy to solve if you were to show a test document which would allow other to reproduce the problem. No need to complain to anybody. In fact the package documentation tells you which option to use if you don't want the integral signs from `wasysym`...

Comment: Load `wasysym` after `amsmath`: [Problems with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336043/problems-with-amsmath). Admittedly, the `wasysym` documentation contains a wrong statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 2 of the [`wasysym` package documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/wasysym.pdf/0) will tell you about the `nointegrals` option which avoids this conflict and let's you keep the normal integral signs (which might or might not be what you want):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\RequirePackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter's content...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not think packages should redefine things distributed by the Latex Project, but define new ones with the package name used as prefix.  Same as done for Emacs Packages.

Comment: @Mahavir This would make a package for redefining symbols pretty useless. If it would use other macro names you couldn't reuse your equations in other documents.

Comment: Is it common that people don't like the equation rendering by the Latex Team ?  If I am using a chemistry package, it would be good to know what I am using.

Comment: @Mahavir This won't change the rendering of equations, just the font of some symbols.